# How do you debug a custom Chromecast Receiver on Nexus Player?

Tags: google-cast

I want to debug a custom Chromecast receiver application on a Nexus Player. I've added the serial number / CSSN to my application whitelist. When I do the same for the Chromecast dongle, I'm able to attach the chrome debugger through ipaddress:9222. However, when trying the same using the IP:9222 port of the Nexus Player, I am unable to connect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use chrome://inspect. Quoting [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv#debugging):

> - On your development machine, open a Chrome browser window and navigate to chrome://inspect .
>
> Note: This is different than debugging for a Chromecast device, where
>   you navigate to your receiver's IP address on port 9222.
>
> - Click the inspect link to bring the receiver into the debugger.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The essence is that he needs to access chrome://inspect which I had mentioned, did you even read the post/response or have a saved response somewhere that you copy and paste here???

Comment: What Daniel means is that your answer is *very* short on detail here.

Comment: an answer doesn't need to be long; if there is a minimum length required beyond what is currently enforced in the editor, make the change there so what I am saying is that my short answer is the piece that poster was missing, why do I need to add unneeded comments when it can be given in a short sentence? Did he even wait to see if the poster was happy with that answer or not? Daniel doesn't have the domain expertise here on this subject so he cannot judge whether a short answer is a good answer or not.

Comment: "The essence is that he needs to access chrome://inspect" -- your answer should explain, in greater detail, what "access chrome://inspect" means. Having a link is nice, but then the next time Google reorganizes its documentation, and that link starts returning a 404, this answer becomes tantamount to useless. "Daniel doesn't have the domain expertise here" -- but *I* do, and *I* had no idea what you are talking about without clicking the link. "have a saved response" -- it is from [the documentation for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, it seems you edited my answer and added two of the steps required in the answer. So here is my question: if the link to the doc doesn't work any more, can someone read your answer and get that working? You missed out a few crucial steps (if you believe the answer should be complete); for example, I can open my laptop and follow the steps you added and go to chrome://inspect". Unless I have done the earlier steps from the doc, I am not going to get anywhere. So if you think a complete answer should be there, yours is also not adequate, is it??

Comment: "if the link to the doc doesn't work any more, can someone read your answer and get that working?" -- it is closer to being usable than what you had originally supplied as an answer. "You missed out a few crucial steps" -- then edit the answer and add them.

Comment: No, then it will be a static copy of page; information on the page can change but if I copy the info here, it won't change along with the original content so that is why providing a link has an advantage. I agree that the link may change but if that happens, it is a big hint for the user to go and search on the doc site for Google Cast and he will find his answer.